Looped RMarkdown Render with flextable Fails if Variables are Included in Table Conditional Formatting when Parallelized
Once I wrote out the title, I realized how specific to me this problem is. I use loops to render .docx reports from an .rmd template that includes flextable tables with conditional formatting. I finally figured out how parallelization in R works (kind of), and I tried to convert my for loops to foreach () %dopar% {} expressions. It didn't work. I've been playing around with it, and I think the problem is from having a variable set in the main script included in the flextable conditional formatting. It's only a problem with %dopar%; it works fine with %do%. Under these specific circumstances, I get an error that the object isn't found.
Here are some hopefully reproducible minimal examples:
Main Script
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

boolean <- TRUE

tables <- list()

for (n in 1:10) {
  tables[[n]] <- iris %>%
    slice_sample(n = 20)
}

number_of_cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
clusters <- parallel::makeCluster(number_of_cores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(clusters)

foreach (
  x = 1:10,
  .export = c("boolean", "tables"),
  .packages = c("dplyr", "flextable", "officer"),
  .verbose = TRUE
) %dopar%
  {
    rmarkdown::render("Template.rmd", output_file = paste0("Iris Subset ", x))
  }

.rmd Template with "boolean" Variable Outside of flextable. This runs successfully with %dopar% in the main script and is the desired output
---
title: "Iris Data"
output: word_document
date: ""
---

```{r table}
if (boolean) {
flextable(tables[[x]]) %>%
  bg(i = ~ (Species == "setosa"), bg = "yellow", part = "body") %>%
  autofit()
} else {
  flextable(tables[[x]]) %>%
  bg(i = ~ (Species == "versicolor"), bg = "skyblue", part = "body") %>%
  autofit()
}

.rmd Template with "boolean" Variable in flextable Conditional Formatting. This runs successfully with %do% in the main script producing the same output as the first template, but with %dopar% it produces the error: Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'boolean' not found"
---
title: "Iris Data"
output: word_document
date: ""
---

```{r table}
flextable(tables[[x]]) %>%
  bg(i = ~ (Species == "setosa" & boolean), bg = "yellow", part = "body") %>%
  bg(i = ~ (Species == "versicolor" & !boolean), bg = "skyblue", part = "body") %>%
  autofit()
```

Passing the value as a param through rmarkdown::render resulted in the same outcome. Does anyone have any idea how I can work around this?

I would be careful relying on globally defined variables in an Rmarkdown workflow. The canonical approach would be to use params in the YAML header and to pass these parameter explicitly to the render process.
parallel.Rmd
N.B. I gave the parameter some defaults to be able to run it also by hand (or Ctrl-Shift-K) but this is optional.
---
title: "Iris Data"
output: word_document
date: ""
params:
  boolean: false
  tables: !r list(iris)
  x: 1
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r table}
if (params$boolean) {
  flextable(params$tables[[params$x]]) %>%
    bg(i = ~ (Species == "setosa"), bg = "yellow", part = "body") %>%
    autofit()
} else {
  flextable(params$tables[[params$x]]) %>%
    bg(i = ~ (Species == "versicolor"), bg = "skyblue", part = "body") %>%
    autofit()
}
```

parallel.R
Make sure you force R to use a dedicated copy of idx by using local (otherwise all render processes receive the same value of x):
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

boolean <- TRUE

tables <- list()

for (n in 1:10) {
  tables[[n]] <- iris %>%
    slice_sample(n = 20)
}

number_of_cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
clusters <- parallel::makeCluster(number_of_cores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(clusters)

foreach (
  idx = 1:10,
  .verbose = TRUE
) %dopar%
  {
    local({
      x <- idx 
      rmarkdown::render(here::here("parallel.Rmd"), 
                        output_file = paste0("Iris Subset Sample", x), 
                        params = list(boolean = boolean, tables = tables, x = x))
    })
    
  }


This solved problems I didn't even realize I had, thank you! Something weird is happening, though. I am trying to generate 213 reports, and when I run the loop in parallel as you wrote several of the docx files are missing or didn't render correctly. It says nothing in the verbose output about why this might be. There isn't anything about any of the reports that should cause them to fail - they all render successfully individually. Is 213 just too many to do at once?
